# Polymer 2.0 :Please Explain the how the Observer method is working in this code?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

This is the code snippet but I'm not able to understand how the observer method is working

```
 static get properties() {
  return {
    selected: {
      type: Object,
      observer: '_selectedChanged'
    }
  };
}

_selectedChanged(selected, oldSelected) {
  if (oldSelected) oldSelected.removeAttribute('selected');
  if (selected) selected.setAttribute('selected', '');
}

connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();

  this.selected = this.firstElementChild;
}
```

full code: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-2-carousel/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3

What is selected and oldselected and how can we do oldSelected.removerAttribute?
Are these objects of elements?
Please elaborate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selected` is property of element. It's value is some HTML element (in this case it's always img i think) so, in `selected` property there is always saved reference to `img` somewhere in html. When this property change, function `_selectedChanged` is called with 2 arguments. first argument is new image that is currently saved in `selected` and second argument is old image(previous value of `selected`).

further in tutorial you can see code

```
  const elem = this.selected.nextElementSibling;
  if (elem) {
    this.selected = elem;
  }
```

where is shown that `const elem` takes some html element and put it into `this.selected`.

So inside function `_selectedChanged` they removed html attribute from old image that was previously selected (so it was visible on screen) and added new html attribute to new image that should be visible on screen for now.

You can imagine that `img` with attribute `selected` is the only one that is shown on the screen at the time

I hope you understand my explanation. My english isn't 100% so if you have question, ask me and i can try to explain it more.

**EDIT**

Some example with binding and observer:

Let's say we have some `paper-input` which should show some results (articles for example) based on value of this input. So we have some HTML:

```
<paper-input value="{{search}}" label="Find articles"></paper-input>
```

this is primitive. Just some `paper-input` with value stored in `search` property. inside script tag:

```
    Polymer({
        is: 'test-el',

        properties: {
            search: {
                type: String,
                observer: "_findResults"
            },
            articles: {
                type: Array
            }
        },

        _findResults() {
            this.set("articles", ['firstArticle', 'secondArticle', Math.random()]);
        },
    });
```

Explain: we defined property `search` and `articles`. Whenever property search changes, it calls function `_findResults` (because of observer). Function _findResults do only one thing. `this.set("articles")` is almost same as `this.articles =`. More about this can be found in [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data). So `this.set("articles", ['firstArticle', 'secondArticle', Math.random()]);` means it creates array and set it to `articles` property. and now, when we have some array that is changing everytime user enter some value in `paper-input`, we can add some HTML to show these articles:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{articles}}" as="item">
  [[item]] <br>
</template>
```

I made also fiddle, so you can play with it and understand it a little bit more.
https://jsfiddle.net/2va41sy0/1/

Your question at the beginning was almost same in difference that they stored in some property reference to HTML object and not only just string. This is also about understand some basics of javascript and not polymer

Comment: can you please write a little code where you change the text value of some div when a button is pressed or something else to demonstrate the functioning of the observer. I'll be really thankful if you can do that please

Comment: thnx a lot man!
I really do owe you you one!
(apologies for the late reply)